# How to orderby desc or asc in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have array filled objects, and I want to orderby them but I couldnt do.

This is my array with objects :

[image]

I want to orderby according to "Tutar". How can I do this ?

**EDİTED**

[image]

*It comes to me wrong as u see but I solved with this :*

```
tutar.sort(function(a,b) {
                    if (parseInt(a.Tutar.toLowerCase()) < parseInt(b.Tutar.toLowerCase())) return -1;
                    if (parseInt(a.Tutar.toLowerCase()) > parseInt(b.Tutar.toLowerCase())) return 1;
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Sort tutar by "Tutar" in ascending order:

```
 var dataAsc = tutar.sort(function(a, b) {
        return Number(a.Tutar) - Number(b.Tutar);
    });
```

Now if u want to sort in descending order

```
var dataDsc =  dataAsc.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

Ascending:

```
tutar.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.Tutar.toLowerCase() < b.Tutar.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if(a.Tutar.toLowerCase() > b.Tutar.toLowerCase()) return 1;
});
```

Descending:

```
tutar.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.Tutar.toLowerCase() > b.Tutar.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if(a.Tutar.toLowerCase() < b.Tutar.toLowerCase()) return 1;
});
```

Comment: This is work but there is a problem. look at my edited Img. I use  descending  but it comes not exactly right. I think because of comma','.

Comment: Please look order u ll understand what I mean